# "Add To Cart" Button in DataList ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, call, postback, datalist

I Need to Add a button **Add To Cart**  in `Data-list`.

The problem is, When i Click on `btn` **ADD Button**, `Datalist1_ItemCommand()` is never reached, but  a **Postback event occurs**

I need to Add a Button *that reads the current item values & performs some operations* on it.

ASP Code

```
    <asp:DataList ID="DL_Products" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" OnItemCommand="Datalist1_ItemCommand">    
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="Item">
            <div class="title">
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Brand" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Brand") %>'></asp:Label>                    
            </div>                
            <div class="Info">  
                Price/Piece :
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Price" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price") %>'></asp:Label>
                Rs
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="btn" CommandName="AddtoCart" runat="server" Text="Add" />
            </div>    
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

C#/ Code Behind :

```
protected void Datalist1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "AddtoCart")
    {
        Label l1 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lbl_Price");
        string a = l1.Text;
        Response.Write(l1.Text);
    }
}


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        load_User_data();
        Brand_SelectedIndexChanged(null, null);
        load_data();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to bind data to grid each time not in !IsPostBack

Comment: I am not sure why this is happening to you, code seems ok . But if you want you can use the `OnClick`  event and use that .

Comment: @Amit he is binding data if the it is `!Postback` thats the way to do it.

Comment: You should keep just the important part of code in your snippet. Remove all fields but one. It will make it more likely to be tried.

Answer (score -1):

add         if(!ispostback){  bind datalist}  on page load